# get lines and labels from matplotlib.axes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I need to get the lines generated when plotting a pandas dataframe.

In the code bellow tried two ways, each have a problem

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
#ax1.plot(df)      #no labels
#ax1 = df.plot()   #new figure 
plt.show()

lines = ax1.get_lines()
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
```

I intend to get the lines and labels to use on [matplotlib.widgets.CheckButtons](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html)

My real df is multiindexed but I hope that doesn't interfere with the question, please tell me if I need to be more precise about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
df.plot(ax=ax1)
```

in place of `ax1 = df.plot()` that creates new plot.
The option `ax=ax1` declares that the axes `ax1` is to use for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I used the official reference you referenced as an example to clearly show how to get the data in a data frame format. You can use `iterrows()` to get the rows of a data frame one by one.See [iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s0 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s1 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t,'s0':s0,'s1':s1,'s2':s2})

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx)
    print(row)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l0, = ax.plot(df['t'], df['s0'], visible=False, lw=2, color='k', label='2 Hz')
l1, = ax.plot(df['t'], df['s1'], lw=2, color='r', label='4 Hz')
l2, = ax.plot(df['t'], df['s2'], lw=2, color='g', label='6 Hz')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

lines = [l0, l1, l2]

# Make checkbuttons with all plotted lines with correct visibility
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)

def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I was not very clear with my doubt or I have problem understanding the vocabulary. Didn't need to get the data from the dataframe but the line objects. Since the df have a variable number of columns, the part of l0, l1, l2 = ... was something would not work for me.